# Is it possible to query aggregations on NEST for multiple term fields (.NET)?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Below is the NEST query and aggregations:

```
        Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<ConferenceWrapper>, QueryContainer> query =
            q =>
            q.Term(p => p.type, "conference")
            // && q.Term(p => p.conference.isWaitingAreaCall, true)
            && q.Range(d => d.Field("conference.lengthSeconds").GreaterThanOrEquals(minSeconds))
            && q.DateRange(qd => qd.Field("conference.firstCallerStart").GreaterThanOrEquals(from.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")))
            && q.DateRange(qd => qd.Field("conference.firstCallerStart").LessThanOrEquals(to.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")));
        Func<AggregationContainerDescriptor<ConferenceWrapper>, IAggregationContainer> waitingArea =
            a => a
            .Terms("both", t => t
            .Field(p => p.conference.orgNetworkId) // seems ignore this field
            .Field(p => p.conference.isWaitingAreaCall)
            // .Field(new Field(  p => p.conference.orgNetworkId + "-ggg-" + p.conference.networkId)
            .Size(300)
            .Aggregations(a2 => a2.Sum("sum-length", d2 => d2.Field("conference.lengthSeconds"))));
```

I have called `.Field(p => p.conference.orgNetworkId)` followed by `.Field(p => p.conference.isWaitingAreaCall)` But it seems the NEST client tries to ignore the first field expression.

Is is possible to have multiple fields to be the terms group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't support a terms aggregation on multiple fields directly; the calls to `.Field(...)` within NEST are assignative rather than additive, so the last call will overwrite any previously set values.

In order to aggregate on multiple fields, you can either

1. Create a composite field at index time that incorporates the values that you wish to aggregate on

   *or*
2. Use a [Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) to generate the terms on which to aggregate at query time, by combining the two field values.

The performance of the first option will be better than the second.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Yes, It behaves something like overwrite the previous `Field` in NEST.